# Passing data from UI controller to Javasript it loses some data

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, .net, json

I am returning my data from my UI controller and I have two objects of the same type in the data which are a certain entity. You can see they both contain values and if you were to fully expand either they are assigned the correct values.

[image: UI Controller]

Now If you look in the javascript it loses all the values on the second entity of the same type. I am showing one of the data objects in the console

[image: JS image]

I am just wondering if anyone knows whats going on and if it is possible to pass a data object with Json that contains two entities of the same type per data objects.

Thanks!

Comment: It looks like you have preserve object references enabled in the JSON serializer. Check out https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/PreserveObjectReferences.htm.

Comment: Yes I believe you are correct. Going to look into it.

Answer (score 0):

This javascript fixed my issue as it now makes the reference values look at the actual values. I know the 4 is hard coded but there are only every 4 elements in the return set and they always have the same values on them except one column so hard coded value of 4 is acceptable in this case.

```
options.data.forEach(function (element) {
            if (element.FromCurrency.$ref == 4 && element.ToCurrency.$ref == 4) {
                element.FromCurrency = options.data.find(x => x.ToCurrency.$id = '4').ToCurrency;
                element.ToCurrency = options.data.find(x => x.ToCurrency.$id = '4').ToCurrency;
            }
            else if (element.ToCurrency.$ref == 4) {
                element.ToCurrency = options.data.find(x => x.ToCurrency.$id = '4').ToCurrency;
            }
        });
```